# Swift Get Specific Value From Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a specific value from Firebase Database. I looked some of the documents such as Google's, but I couldn't do it. Here is the JSON file of the database:

```
{
    "Kullanıcı" : {
        "ahmetozrahat25" : {
            "E-Mail" : "ahmetozrahat25@gmail.com",
            "Yetki" : "user"
        },
        "banuozrht" : {
            "E-Mail" : "banuozrahat@gmail.com",
            "Yetki" : "user"
        }
    }
}
```

Swift Code:

```
ref?.child("Kullanıcı").child(userName.text!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let item = snapshot.value as? String{
        self.changedName = item
    }
})
```

I want to get `E-Mail` value of a user, not everybody's. How can I do that?

Comment: you want us to write the code for you??You can show what have you tried so that we can look and help.

Comment: I wanted an example but you'r right i just edited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At last I found a solution. If I declare a var and try to use later it returns nil, but if I try use `snapshot.value as? String` it's ok. Here is a example I did.

```
    ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
    handle: FIRDatabaseHandle?

    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    handle = ref?.child("Kullanıcı").child((user?.uid)!).child("Yetki").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let value = snapshot.value as? String{

            if snapshot.value as? String == "admin"{
                self.items.append("Soru Gönder")
                self.self.tblView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: you have the first if statement initializing the variable 'value' equal to snapshot.value , so the next if statement can be the variable 'value' compared to "admin", else the first assignment for 'value' is wasted code

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the snapshot will contain a dictionary of child values. To access them, cast the snapshot.value as a Dictionary and then accessing the individual children is a snap (shot, lol)

```
ref?.child("Kullanıcı").child(userName.text!)
                       .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

    let email = userDict["E-Mail"] as! String
    let yetki = userDict["Yetki"] as! String
    print("email: \(email)  yetki: \(yetki)")
})
```

Comment: I thought about that, you are right but it returns nil

Answer (score 2):

Add the "E-Mail" child to the query.

```
ref?.child("Kullanıcı").child(userName.text!).child("E-Mail").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let item = snapshot.value as? String{
        self.changedName = item
    }
})
```