# Unable to fetch and print a single value from a Firebase Database with Swift 5 (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Aim:** Trying to print out the value "email" from my Firebase Realtime Database, into the XCode 11 console. Please see the provided code and JSON excerpt.

**Comment:** A question that seems to be rather obvious, however after trying several suggestions, including [Swift Get Specific Value From Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256523/swift-get-specific-value-from-firebase-database), and the Firebase documentation, I still seem to miss something.

**Code:**

```
func updateRiskValue() {

    var databaseReference: DatabaseReference!

    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    databaseReference.child("users").child((currentUser?.uid)!).child("email").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let valueRisk = value?["email"] as? String ?? ""

        print(valueRisk)

    }) {(error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

@IBAction func riskSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {

    updateRiskValue()

}
```

**JSON Excerpt:**

```
"users" : {
"ihhqjBDfIYeyl5QqsnFl1LVrXRG3" : {
  "email" : "alexander@gmail.com",
  "isCheckedCount" : 3,
  "kycitems" : {
    "Attach Government Documents" : {
      "isChecked" : false
    },
    "Client Knowledge" : {
      "isChecked" : true
    },
    "Contact Information" : {
      "isChecked" : true
    },
    "PEP Check" : {
      "isChecked" : true
    },
    "Risk Assessment" : {
      "isChecked" : true
    },
    "Source of Wealth" : {
      "isChecked" : true
    },
    "Transit Account Holders" : {
      "isChecked" : true
    },
    "Transit Account Numbers" : {
      "isChecked" : false
    }
  },
  "password" : "123123",
  "riskValue" : "1",
  "todos" : {
    "Hello" : {
      "isChecked" : false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an observer to `/Users/$uid/email`, so the `snapshot` you get contains just the value of the `email` property. You are treating as a dictionary however, which explains why your code doesn't work.

To fix this, get the simple value from the

```
databaseReference.child("users").child((currentUser?.uid)!).child("email").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let valueRisk = snapshot.value as? String
    print(valueRisk)

}) {(error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However when applied, the function only returns "nil".

Comment: Oops, I had a type in the code snippet, and still tried to cast it to a dictionary. It's now casting to a string, which should work (if the value is present).